# How to prepare AVCHD on a PC for Mac use later?

Tags: editing, file-formats, conversion, mac, avchd

I recently began a job in IT and part of my role involves recording at some company events. However, it isn't my role to edit the videos themselves. These files need to be handed off to a Mac user who has Adobe Premier. I, however use a PC (Windows 7).

I am using a Panasonic HC-V520 which records AVCHD, and only have the typical included Windows 7 software. I need to somehow get the video to a Mac user (who has Adobe Premier) so that she may view and edit. It would also be nice, if possible, to store the files on our (Windows) server for archiving purposes.

I've found so far that I can play and store the .mts files on my PC and play them in VLC and Windows Media Player, but getting them from the PC to a Mac is really a pain-- Even if I wanted to edit them on my PC they don't burn to a playable DVD in Windows Media Center, and the files aren't playable on a Mac at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do anything to the files, Premiere Pro should be able to handle them. Just copy them to a USB drive and hand them off to your editor.

NEVER convert your video files prior to editing. You'll lose quality for no reason.

If the Mac won't open them, try another media player such as [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). For a PC, I'd say you may need to install Quicktime as it comes with a codec that may be required, but on a Mac that should be preinstalled anyway. If that doesn't work, update your operating system. Or just try to import them to Premiere, if it doesn't work, update Premiere.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds more like a Filesystem related question... For a couple of years now both Windows and osx can read ExFat formatted drives, so as moritzlost mentioned, leave the files untouched and just copy them to an ExFat drive. BTW not touching the avchd files also includes not changing the directory structure, in case your idea was to just copy out the mts files from the folders.

Comment: Actually that might lead to a problem on a Mac. If the Mac recognizes the avchd file structure, it will display it as a clip show instead of a folder. You can still import the videos into premiere, but the OS will prevent you from accessing it's content directly. This becomes a problem if you move the folder to a different directory, because you can't relink the media files. This can be solved by renaming the avchd folder.

Comment: I didn't mean the folder name but the structure of the files in the folder. At least when the recording device used spanning clips (recordings that are split into different 2gb pieces), this was "destroyed" when taking out the actual video clips from the folder. Often this is only detected by the NLE if the directory contains the files in the original structure with the accompanying metadata.